# Weird segmentation fault inside of XPutImage in Xlib

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, gdb, x11, xlib

I am making a program that displays a taskbar with icons from open windows. I have made a function that takes two pointers and some additional auxiliary data. The two pointers, icon_Data and icon_Data_Ptr points to data returned by the atom _NET_WM_ICON and points to the specific icon I am going to use, respectively. Here is the function below:

```
static Pixmap create_Pixmap_From_Icon_Data(Taskbar * taskbar, Taskbar_Item * taskbar_Item, uint32_t * icon_Data_Ptr, uint32_t * icon_Data) {
    Pixmap icon_Pixmap = XCreatePixmap(taskbar->display, taskbar->parent, (unsigned int) icon_Data_Ptr[0], (unsigned int) icon_Data_Ptr[1], 32);

    XImage * x_Image = XCreateImage(taskbar->display, taskbar->visual, 32, ZPixmap, 2, (char *) &icon_Data_Ptr, (unsigned int) icon_Data_Ptr[0], (unsigned int) icon_Data_Ptr[1], 32, 0);

    GC temp_GC = XCreateGC(taskbar->display, icon_Pixmap, 0, 0);

    XPutImage(taskbar->display, icon_Pixmap, temp_GC, x_Image, 0, 0, 0, 0, icon_Data_Ptr[0], icon_Data_Ptr[1]);
    x_Image->data = (char *) icon_Data;

    XDestroyImage(x_Image);
    XFreeGC(taskbar->display, temp_GC);

    return icon_Pixmap;
}
```

Whenever I try to run the program it segfaults around half of the time. The stack-trace from Gdb is below:

```
#0  __memmove_sse2_unaligned_erms ()
    at ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/memmove-vec-unaligned-erms.S:262
#1  0x00007ffff7c9f6b0 in memcpy (__len=<optimized out>, 
    __src=0x7fffffffdd48, __dest=<optimized out>)
    at /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/string_fortified.h:34
#2  SendZImage (dest_scanline_pad=<optimized out>, 
    dest_bits_per_pixel=32, req_yoffset=0, 
    req_xoffset=<optimized out>, image=0x459dd0, 
    req=<optimized out>, dpy=0x4062a0)
    at ../../src/PutImage.c:795
#3  PutImageRequest (gc=<optimized out>, 
    dest_scanline_pad=<optimized out>, dest_bits_per_pixel=32, 
    req_height=<optimized out>, req_width=<optimized out>, 
    y=<optimized out>, x=<optimized out>, req_yoffset=0, 
    req_xoffset=<optimized out>, image=0x459dd0, 
    d=<optimized out>, dpy=0x4062a0) at ../../src/PutImage.c:861
#4  PutSubImage (dpy=0x4062a0, d=<optimized out>, 
    gc=<optimized out>, image=0x459dd0, 
    req_xoffset=<optimized out>, req_yoffset=<optimized out>, 
    x=0, y=0, req_width=48, req_height=48, 
    dest_bits_per_pixel=32, dest_scanline_pad=32)
    at ../../src/PutImage.c:899
#5  0x00007ffff7c9faae in XPutImage (dpy=0x4062a0, d=23068677, 
    gc=0x459e60, image=0x459dd0, req_xoffset=0, req_yoffset=0, 
    x=0, y=0, req_width=48, req_height=48)
    at ../../src/PutImage.c:1018
#6  0x00000000004022bc in create_Pixmap_From_Icon_Data (
    taskbar=0x4088e0, taskbar_Item=0x413760, 
    icon_Data_Ptr=0x4579b8, icon_Data=0x413890) at taskbar.c:206
#7  0x0000000000402032 in find_And_Set_Pixmap_From_Property_Data
    (taskbar=0x4088e0, taskbar_Item=0x413760, 
    icon_Data=0x413890, item_Count=72012) at taskbar.c:231
#8  0x0000000000401c48 in set_Taskbar_Item_Icon_Pixmap (
    taskbar=0x4088e0, taskbar_Item=0x413760, instance=0x408860)
    at taskbar.c:256
#9  0x000000000040196c in add_Instance_To_New_Taskbar_Item (
    taskbar=0x4088e0, instance=0x408860) at taskbar.c:315
#10 0x000000000040170e in add_Window_If_Necessary (
--Type <RET> for more, q to quit, c to continue without paging--
    taskbar=0x4088e0, window=18876630) at taskbar.c:386
#11 0x0000000000402ae5 in iterate_Through_All_Windows (
    taskbar=0x4088e0, display=0x4062a0, screen=0, 
    iterator_Callback=0x401690 <add_Window_If_Necessary>)
    at taskbar_Test.c:31
#12 0x0000000000402997 in setup_Taskbar (taskbar=0x7fffffffdfb8, 
    display=0x4062a0, screen=0, parent=23068674, 
    visual=0x408430, colormap=23068673) at taskbar_Test.c:42
#13 0x00000000004027bf in main () at taskbar_Test.c:72
```

During other times I have debugged it, I have checked to make sure that icon_Data_Ptr has enough data for XCreatePixmap to function, it does. What is weird, however, I found that when Gdb steps inside of XCreatePixmap, the pointer to the data within the function is a different address than outside of the function. Also, in playing around with GDB, I have found that when I am inside of XCreateImage, the data pointer for the image does not contain enough data for the function to work. I also dumped the memory pointing to the image data at the function call of XCreateImage and inside of the function call of XCreateImage. I imported this data using Gimp. The image looked like the chrome browser icon outside of the function but inside of the function it looked like a mix of orderly and random colors that did not resemble the chrome icon.

In addition to using Gdb, I tried to see if this was a compiler bug by using Clang in the place of GCC; it produced the same error.

I do not know what I am doing wrong that is causing this segmentation fault, any help would be appreaciated.

Comment: After calling Xlib's functions, you should check the returned values. If those returned values are pointers, check if they are not null and then only proceed. You don't seem to be checking the results of `XCreateImage`, `XCreatePixmap` and `XCreateGC`.

Comment: Also, many of the function arguments are shown as `optimized` in GDB stack trace. Are you compiling in Release mode? Please compile your program with `-g3` compiler option in Debug mode. That way, actual values for `optimized` will be shown (I hope).

Comment: Just now, I ran my program using Gdb and I printed the output of XCreateImage, XCreatePixmap, and XCreateGC; they all gave valid values and still crashed. Also, my program is not optimized and has the max debug settings set, it is just that libX11 and libc are optimized. I have, however, installed the dbgsym packages for both of those libraries.

Comment: Since the problem is shown in `memcpy`, please check if you have passed any size related parameter and whether that parameter is proper. It seems program crashes when trying to access illegal memory which normally occurs when trying to access memory out of bounds.

Answer (score 0):

I stepped through the machine code using GDB and I saw this before the function call to `XCreateImage`: `lea    -0x38(%rbp),%rdi`. This loads the address of a local variable located in the red-zone into the `rdi` register which later gets moved into the `r9` register to be the 6th parameter as per the System V ABI for Amd64 (https://uclibc.org/docs/psABI-x86_64.pdf). So this means that instead of passing the pointer value of `icon_Data_Ptr`, I was passing the address of where the pointer was stored: `(char *) &icon_Data_Ptr`. This caused a bad XImage structure to be passed to XPutImage and this caused the segmentation fault.